# Monitoring Outgoing Requests For Images Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi I've been trying to figure out a way monitor image requests for image views when using an external url, but I just can't figure it out. I've tried:

- The 'packet capture' application, when I turn request monitoring on, the image isn't even requested.
- Monitoring the outgoing requests from my device using fiddler, in this case the images are loaded but I can't see any signs of requests that were made to retrieve the images(the first time the images are loaded, so they couldn't possibly be loaded from cache)

Are there any other more reliable means of monitoring outgoing image requests without relaying upon tools that require root access to the device?

Comment: iOS or Android?  An actual device, or a sim/emulator?

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that, its an android device

Comment: Thanks Jason, but all the recommended tools required root access to the device, which I don't have, I've tried rooting my device(Huawei P8 Lite), Its not as simple as ABC, too much of a hassle for something as simple as rooting a device.

Comment: your only option is probably to create a local wifi network on your PC, connect your device to it, and then to run a packet sniffer on that local network on your PC

Comment: I ran the app on an emulator and it was able to view the network traffic easier, don't know why I never thought of this earlier, because, essentially, the emulator accesses the internet through the computer and used I charles web debugger which was able to pick up the image requests easily. Thanks for all your support Jason